# How to compile php with additional extension

Tags: php, aws-lambda, serverless

I want to run php script on AWS Lambda with Serverless framework. I compiled php binary with

```
--with-curl --with-openssl=PATH --with-zlib
```

flags, but script use redis, so I need compile php with redis extension. How can I do this?

Comment: follow the [instructions](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/INSTALL.markdown)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I see that the instruction shows how to compile the redis separately and then add this extension. But I can not configure the compiled binary php file to include this redis extension

Comment: "you still need to enable the module in the PHP config file. To do so, either edit your php.ini or add a redis.ini file in /etc/php5/conf.d with the following contents: extension=redis.so"

Comment: @AlanBirtles AWS lambda doesn't allow configuring php.ini, that's why i should use precompiled php with redis. How can I compile php with redis?